# Translucent Navigation Bar (Android 4.4) — Show Content Underneath

Tags: android, navigation, overlay, transparent, android-4.4-kitkat

Does anyone know how to make the translucent navigation bar (on 4.4) overlap and show the content view (in this case, a ListView) under it?

If may appear transparent in this screenshot (which is of the app I'm currently developing for my employer), but if the list goes on below the bottom of the screen, the list items that go under the navigation bar are covered by it and cannot be seen.

An example of what I'm looking to do is the Google Now component of the Google Edition Launcher on the Nexus 5. The navigation bar is completely transparent and shows the TextViews and everything under it, the only part of the navigation bar you see if the outlines of the buttons themselves.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found half of a solution.

It appears the use of the `android:fitsSystemWindows` theme attribute is what prevents the behavior I want. If I set this attribute to false, the navigation bar displays a ListView as it scrolls underneath it; however, the list also goes under the action bar now which is a problem.

**SOLUTION**:

http://mindofaandroiddev.wordpress.com/2013/12/28/making-the-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-transparent-with-a-listview-on-android-4-4-kitkat/